# Android Vcard data Read functionalities

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

How to read the v-card data for ORG filed ?
     Example : ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
     how to read above field in vcard type in store to string in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
Organization organization = vcard.getOrganization();
                if (organization != null) {
                    List<String> values = organization.getValues();
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                        n_company = values.get(i);

                    }
                }

                    }
                }
```